# JSON.parse unexpected character error

Tags: javascript, json

I get this error:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character

when I run this statement in firebug:

```
JSON.parse({"balance":0,"count":0,"time":1323973673061,"firstname":"howard","userId":5383,"localid":1,"freeExpiration":0,"status":false});
```

Why is it so? The JSON string seems correct to me and I also tested it using JSHint. The passed object in the above case is a server response with content type set to `application/json`

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You're not parsing a string, you're parsing an already-parsed object :)

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse('{"creditBalance":0,...,"starStatus":false}');
//                    ^                                          ^
//                    if you want to parse, the input should be a string 

var obj2 = {"creditBalance":0,...,"starStatus":false};
// or just use it directly.
```

Comment: I want to upvote for the first sentence, but why would you re-parse?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, Mathletics: Right. Updated.

Comment: @Mathletics By all accounts JSON.parse does some security check. N.T.

Comment: That's hilarious. Love it. <3

Comment: I am getting undefined on data.results (data is a JSON object). Stack is telling me to make it a js object by data = JSON.parse(data). But I am getting JSON.parse unexpected character error.

Answer (score 41):

You can make sure that the object in question is stringified before passing it to parse function by simply using  `JSON.stringify()` .

Updated your line below,

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"balance":0,"count":0,"time":1323973673061,"firstname":"howard","userId":5383,"localid":1,"freeExpiration":0,"status":false}));`

or if you have JSON stored in some variable:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourJSONobject));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify is the boss.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Not true for the OP, but this error can be caused by using single quotation marks (`'`) instead of double (`"`) for strings.

The [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires double quotation marks for strings.

E.g:

```
JSON.parse(`{"myparam": 'myString'}`)
```

gives the error, whereas

```
JSON.parse(`{"myparam": "myString"}`)
```

does not. Note the quotation marks around `myString`.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355724/1461850