# The output of json_encode() a string containing slashes can't be parsed by JSON.parse()

Tags: php, jquery, json

I get a string with the following output from `json_encode`:

```
["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"]
```

I attempt to parse it with the below code, but it gives me an error:

```
var listofshoes = JSON.parse(data); 
for (var i in listofshoes) {
    $('#pgwrapid').append( $("<p>").text(listofshoes[i]));
}
```

```
ERROR: JSON.parse: unexpected character [Break On This Error] return window.JSON.parse( data );`
```

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of backslashes. JSONLint parses it correctly. It's because JSON.parse() must have string parameter and you are passing an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings

> To convert a JSON string into a JavaScript object, you simply pass the
>   JSON into the JSON.parse() method, like this:
>
> `var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Also mentioned here: [JSON.parse unexpected character error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error).

Example:

```
var data = ["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"];

data_string = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(JSON.parse(data_string));    // no error
console.log(JSON.parse(data));           // will show error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str    = '["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail",
"images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"]';
$rst    = json_decode($str);
//print_r($rst);
foreach($rst as $val) {
    echo $val;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Try This.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's an AJAX call somewhere in the omitted code. jQuery AJAX methods decode JSON strings for you, so `JSON.parse()` is not necessary.