# Parse Json in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse json in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

I need to parse this JSON in JavaScript or jQuery. Please help me in getting the list of product in the below JSON.

To get the list of product

```
{
    "main": {
        "ProductsData": {
            "Product": {
                "AdjustmentTypeID": "0",
                "BrandID": "4",
                "BrandName": "Joseph Joseph",
                "ChildrenGenerated": "False",
                "Cost": "8.50",
                "Description": "<span style=\"line-height: 120%; \">The ingenious dual-chamber design of this measuring jug eliminates the need for separate measuring spoons, cups and jugs. Use the small chamber to accurately measure liquids from as little as a single teaspoon (5ml), and then for greater volumes (up to 550ml) simply turn the jug 180&ordm; and use the larger chamber. Made from SAN material. Heat resistant to 90&deg;C \\/ 190&deg;F.<\\/span>\\u000d\\u000a<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:\\u000d\\u000a120%;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none;vertical-align:middle\"><br \\/>\\u000d\\u000aDesign registered<span lang=\"EN-US\"><o:p><\\/o:p><\\/span><\\/p>\\u000d\\u000a<p class=\"BasicParagraph\"><span style=\"font-size:11.0pt;line-height:120%;\\u000d\\u000afont-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:windowtext\"><br \\/>\\u000d\\u000aDimensions&nbsp;&nbsp; 7x 7 x 15cm<o:p><\\/o:p><\\/span><\\/p>",
                "DownloadFile": "",
                "InternalCode": "502842009381 0",
                "IsProductActive": "False",
                "ManufacturerID": "11",
                "ManufacturerName": "Joseph Joseph",
                "OptionMatchGroupID": "",
                "ParentProduct": "",
                "ProductID": "80",
                "ProductName": "2-in-1 Measuring Jug",
                "ProductTypeDescription": "Compound Product",
                "ProductTypeID": "8",
                "SiteID": "57",
                "StockLevel": "",
                "SupplierID": "3",
                "SupplierName": "Joseph Joseph",
                "UseStockControl": "False",
                "VatRate": "20"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`parseJSON` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in jQuery.

Example:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(yourJsonString);
alert(obj.main.ProductsData.Product.Cost);
```

Answer (score 3):

Read JSON from file:

```
myobject = $.parseJSON("myfile.json")
```

Or read JSON from string:

```
myobject = $.parseJSON(jsonString)
```

Now get the data you want:

```
//Loops  into every Product in ProductsData:
$(myobject.main.ProductsData.Product).each(function(index, element){
    //Do something with Product variable such as below
    alert(element.BrandName + ' ' + element.SupplierName);
}
```

Be sure to check your JSON data with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: No, you can't send a filename into the `parseJSON` method.

Comment: @Guffa No, we can. I've done it once. And you can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082929/create-contact-table-from-json-data

Answer (score 2):

Just use `JSON.parse` function ([MDN docu link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse))

```
yourObj = JSON.parse( jsonstring );
```

Afterwards you can access any property of the JSON string via your object, so, e.g.,

```
yourObj['main']['ProductsData']['ProductName']
```

will return

```
"2-in-1 Measuring Jug"
```

in your given example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery function `$.parseJSON(jsonString)` to get the json object

if jsonString stores the the string you given ,

```
jsonObj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

> jsonObj.main.ProductsData.Product

will be an array of products

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript: `JSON.parse(yourjavascriptobjecttoparse);`

Then `var productx = yourjavascriptobjecttoparse['main']['ProductsData']['Product']` to reference the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var object = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Now you can access this object like a native JavaScript Object:

```
object.main.ProductsData.Product.BrandName     // Joseph Joseph
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting JSON plugin for jQuery called [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).

It allows you to both serialize and deserialize JSON.  It works like this:

```
var myObject = { property1: "value1", property2: "value2" };

// Converts myObject to JSON
var serialized = $.toJSON(myObject);

// Parses generated JSON into a new object
var deserialized = $.evalJSON(serialized);
```