# Create contact table from JSON file

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I am new to JSON.

I was doing a project on HTML, JSON and jQuery recently. Thing I want to achieve now is get data from the JSON file and load it into my table. The data was not loaded into my table.

My json file contact.json

```
{
    "length": 2,
    "info": [
        {
            "name":"Sam",
            "email":"fred@server.com",
            "phone":"789456235"
        },
        {
            "name":"Fred",
            "email":"fred@server.com",
            "phone":"125689564"
        }
    ]
}
```

My script to load data:

```
window.onload = function () {
            var contacts;
            setTimeout(function(){  //pass it an anonymous function that calls foo
                          loadData("contact");
                       },2000);
        };

        function loadData(myfile){
           $.getJSON( myfile + ".json", function(data){
            console.log(data)
              $.each(data, function(index, element){
            $.each(element, function(i, item){  
               $('#contacts').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>'+ item.email +'</td><td>' + item.phone + '</td><td>');       
            });
              });
           });
        }
```

My HTML

```
<body>
<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:400px;height:250px;">
    <div title="Home">
        <table id='contacts'></table>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I copied the whole thing from [Create contact table from JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082929/create-contact-table-from-json-data)

This is the error

```
    TypeError: j is undefined
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line 32
```

I'm getting the object in the console. but the data is not loaded. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: `$.parseJSON("../data/" + myfile + ".json");` parses a JSON string to return an Object; it does not fetch data from you JSON file. For that, you'd need to use $.getJSON("../data/" + myfile + ".json", function(data){ //Parse JSON here })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the relative url to a file into the jQuery.parseJSON function.
The [API documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), that jQuery.parseJSON:

> Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript
>   object.

You should first load the content of the json file ([maybe with jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) and pass the result to the parseJSON function.

Second: You're using different IDs for the table in your HTML and in your JavaScript.
"contacts" vs. "contact"

Comment: Your table has an id of "contact" but in jQuery you're trying to access it via "#contacts". ("s" is too much).

Comment: I don't want to hard-code. I want to get data from a JSON file

Comment: Sure, it was just for jsFiddle. I'm sending your json as data to an echo api, so I recieve your data as json (a bit complicated). And I found another bug: In your "append" function you are missing a closing tablerow (</tr>). The last <td> should be </tr>.

Comment: Here is a fully working code sample hosted on my server. So I can use a json file.

http://test.joquery.com/stackoverflow/14558801/

Answer (score 2):

`$.parseJSON()` parses a JSON string to return a JSON object. It does not fetch data from you JSON file. For that, you'd need to use `$.getJSON(url, function(data){ //Parse JSON here })`

Update your `loadData` function to:

```
function loadData(myobject, myfile){
    $.getJSON("../data/" + myfile + ".json", function(data){
        myobject = data;
        $(myobject.info).each(function(index, element){  
            $('#contacts').append('<tr><td>' + element.name + '</td><td>'
            + element.email + '</td><td>'
            + element.phone + '</td><td>');       
        })
    })
};
```

and change your `onLoad` function to:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var contacts;
    setTimeout(function(){
        loadData(contacts, "contact");
    }, 2000);
};
```

Comment: Still I'm not getting data on the page

Comment: Log the result of the callback and see if you're actually getting any data i.e. put a `console.log(data)` before the `myobject = data` line.

Comment: Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
setTimeout(loadData(contacts, "contact"));

This is the error I'm getting

Comment: I'm getting the object in the console. but the data is not loaded

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

because you have array of `info[]`

```
$(function () {
   setTimeout(function(){  //pass it an anonymous function that calls foo
      loadData('contact');
   },2000);
});

function loadData(myfile){
   $.getJSON("../data/" + myfile + ".json", function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, element){
        $.each(element, function(i, item){  
           $('#contacts').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>'+ item.email +'</td><td>' + item.phone + '</td><td>');       
        });
      });
   });
}
```

i have done this on fiddle by creating a var json with all your json values.
<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/vyTjn/</kbd>

Comment: Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
file:///home/sreekeshos/jquery%20ui/index.html.erb
Line 16

Comment: tried that also. Now i get
Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line 32
TypeError: j is undefined
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line 32

Comment: I'm getting the object in the console. but the data is not loaded

Comment: `loadData('contact');` call with `'quotes'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23496/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-jai)

Comment: k. Still im getting the same error TypeError: j is undefined
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line 32

Comment: have you tested with ugrading the jqeery to latest one.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 I get the error.
TypeError: obj is undefined
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js
Line 583