# JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have an json array and i want to parse it in java-script but my jquery gives me following error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

The code in jquery is,on which the error comes:

```
// Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {//error comes on this line.
return window.JSON.parse( data );
}
```

My code is:

```
success: function(msg){
                var test= JSON.parse(msg);
                var question=test.question;
        document.getElementById('question').value=question;
```

I am using the latest version of jquery

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

I am getting this in function(msg):

```
[Object { question=

"What is your religious affiliation?"

,  userQuestionCategoryId=

"1"

}]
```

Here is my Php code:

```
function getquest()
        {
             $id=$this->input->post('qid');
             $data=$this->adminsetting->getquestion($id);
             if(count($data)>0)
             //echo $data[0]->question; 
             echo json_encode($data);
             else
             echo "No Question In database";
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it depends on the data you parse. Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error.

You don't need jQuery as well, to use JSON.parse

Comment: Do you have an example of the json you're trying to parse?

Comment: consoe.log(msg) and see the result , and please add your php code

Comment: FYI: jQuery uses the internal JSON parser if available [(source)](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.parseJSON) so you can just use `$.parseJSON()`

Comment: @Andreas ,so am i doing wrong in my php code??i am using json_encode($data).is there any other way to do it??

Comment: Forget my last (deleted) comment... It looks like `msg` is already a parsed JSON string. Did you try `msg[0].question` ?

Comment: ohhh...yes you are right,msg[0].question works..:( Thanks Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the json i s becomes alredy parsed so i have to just used the index,i am missing to use the index msg[0]. Thats why I am getting problem.

```
success: function(msg){



        document.getElementById('question').value=msg[0].question;

        document.getElementById('id').value=msg[0].userQuestionCategoryId;
        //alert(msg);
        } });
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
{ question=

"What is your religious affiliation?"

,  userQuestionCategoryId=

"1"

}
```

Must be like this:

```
{"question":"What is your religious affiliation?",  "userQuestionCategoryId":"1"}
```