# jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What actually the difference between this?

This works fine:

```
var obj1 = jQuery.parseJSON('{"orderedList": "true"}');
document.write("obj1 "+ obj1.orderedList );
```

but the following does not work:

```
var obj2 = jQuery.parseJSON("{'orderedList': 'true'}");
document.write("obj2 "+ obj2.orderedList );
```

Why is that?

Comment: Few related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/242813/465053) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2275359/465053).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

That's because double quotes is considered standard while single quote is not. This is not really specific to JQuery, but its about [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/). So irrespective of JS toolkit, you should expect same behaviour.

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

**Update**

Or perhaps its a duplicate of [jQuery single quote in JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response)

Answer (score 25):

As per the API documentation, double quotes are considered valid JSON, single quotes aren't.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I vouch for this answer. But one question remains: why double quotes? I can only assume they picked double quotes because it's more common in programming languages to use double quotes for strings. In some languages single quotes are used for single-byte characters, *not* for strings.

Comment: @Tim - see Ck's answer below... Also, note that within a string, you're more likely to use an apostrophe/single quote than a double one, so double quotes to delimit strings is likely to be easier to work with.

Comment: The reasons behind https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627 I don't know. But that RFC is the reason why jQuery picked double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Go to [www.Jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) website and check your single quotes json string you will found that it  is not a valid json string.  Because double quotes json is standard json format.

jsonlint.com is a website to check json format right or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use replace to fix this. This worked for me.

```
var str = "{'orderedList': 'true'}";

str = str.replace(/\'/g, '\"');

JSON.parse(str);
```