# Store and retrieve JavaScript arrays into and from HTML data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

How can a JavaScript array be stored in an HTML custom data attribute?

I've tried every variation of JSON stringification and escaping characters.

What is the precise method to store the array and retrieve it again?

I build the array with `[ $("#firstSelectedElement").val(), $("#secondSelectedElement").val() ]`.  I retrieve `id="storageElement" data-storeIt="stuff"` with `$("#storageElement").data('storeit')`.

I can never seem to retrieve the data as a true array, only an array of characters.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could use the HTML escaped characters in the element `data` attribute to have JSON-like array (encoded are quotes):

```
<div id="demo" data-stuff='[&#34;some&#34;, &#34;string&#34;, &#34;here&#34;]'></div>
```

And then in JavaScript get it without any additional magic:

```
var ar = $('#demo').data('stuff');
```

See this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/).

However, escaping isn't necessary. You can do this, instead:

```
<div id="demo" data-stuff='["some", "string", "here"]'></div>
```

See this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3xfez/).

Comment: Thanks for the update, It worked.
But I don't know why it doesn't works with `data-stuff="['some', 'string', 'here']"` (notice the `'`), any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a million (Y), this is working fine: 
'[&#34;some&#34;, &#34;string&#34;, &#34;here&#34;]'

Comment: @Animesh Singh : You must use a valid JSON, single quote are not valid JSON.

Comment: @nand42 The single quotes issue was what I was encountering. Works like a charm with double quotes!

Comment: Be aware if there is one item in the data it will result in (int) or (string) value. I wrote an answer how to deal with this.

Answer (score 65):

It depends on what type of data you're storing in the array. If it's just strings (as it appears to be) and you have a character that you *know* will never be a part of your data (like the comma in my example below) then I would forget about JSON serialization and just use string.split:

```
<div id="storageElement" data-storeIt="stuff,more stuff"></div>
```

Then when retrieving:

```
var storedArray = $("#storageElement").data("storeIt").split(",");
```

It will handle a bit better than using JSON. It uses less characters and is less "expensive" than `JSON.parse`.

But, if you must, your JSON implementation would look something like this:

```
<div id="storageElement" data-storeIt='["hello","world"]'></div>
```

And to retrieve:

```
var storedArray = JSON.parse($("#storageElement").data("storeIt"));
```

Notice that in this example we had to use semi-quotes (`'`) around the `data-storeIt` property. This is because the JSON syntax requires us to use quotes around the strings in its data.

Comment: LOL. I hate it when that happens. I guess a trivial answer that makes you go, "duh!" is better than no solution at all though!

Comment: @Gracchus I just noticed that you said you used my suggestion, but didn't mark it as the answer. Did it end up not working out for you?

Comment: For Rails dudes: The JSON version mentioned here is how HAML is dealing with array setting e.g.: `%button{data: {ids: ['a','b','c']} }` => `<button data-ids='["a","b","c"]'>`

Comment: @Grinn Do you know why `data-storeIt='["hello","world"]'` works but `data-storeIt="['hello','world']"` doesnt?

Comment: @user814628 Although single quotes are cool in JS, they don't fly in JSON. See this answer for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote

Comment: Use of split(",") is the way to go.  One other note:  You might want to trim each resulting string element, because if your source has spaces after each comma, those spaces will end up in the array elements.  Try this:
`$("#storageElement").data("storeIt").split(",").map( e => e.trim() );`

Comment: It's notable that the solution @Raff suggested uses Arrow Functions which aren't supported in IE < Edge. The equivalent would be `...map(function(s) { return s.trim() })`

Answer (score 10):

The HTML5 data attribute can store only strings, so if you want to store an array you will need to serialize it. JSON will work and it looks like you're on the right path. You just need to use `JSON.parse()` once you retrieve the serialized data:

```
var retrieved_string = $("#storageElement").data('storeit');
var retrieved_array = JSON.parse(retrieved_string);
```

Reviewing the [api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5), jQuery should try to automatically convert a JSON encoded string provided it is properly encoded. Can you give an example of the value you are storing?

Also note that HTML5 data attribute and jQuery `.data()` methods are two distinct things. They interact, but jQuery is more powerful and can store any data type. You could just store a javascript array directly using jQuery without serializing it. But if you need to have it in the markup itself as an HTML5 data attribute, then you are limited only to strings.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, it didn't work with encoded entities for me, but seems that in order to be parsed as an object, the data attribute **must be a well formed JSON object**.

So I was able to use an object with:

```
data-myarray="{&quot;key&quot;: &quot;value&quot;}"
```

or maybe just use single quotes:

```
data-myobject='{"key1": "value1", "key2": value2}'
```

Time to have fun! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can store any object into node like that:

```
$('#storageElement').data('my-array', ['a', 'b', 'c']);

var myArray = $('#storageElement').data('my-array');
```

Comment: what about storring it from html?

Answer (score -1):

If you need nested arrays or just another way to do it. This works:

```js
$('[data-example]').each(function (i, e) {
    var json = $(e).data('example');
  for(var index in json){
    console.log(json[index]["name"] + "=" + json[index]["value"]);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-example='[{"name": "A", "value": 1}, {"name": "B", "value": 2}]' />
<div data-example='[{"name": "C", "value": 3}, {"name": "D", "value": 4}]' />
```

as suggested by [Ulysse BN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6320039/ulysse-bn)

Or with eval() that is a dangerous solution as pointed by [Bonifacius Sarumpaet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12964069/bonifacius-sarumpaet) but works

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-example="[['A', 1], ['B', 2]]" />
<div data-example="[['C', 3], ['D', 4]]" />

<script>
  $('[data-example]').each(function (i, e) {
    var arrayFromText = eval($(e).data('example'));
    console.log(arrayFromText[0][0] + "=" + arrayFromText[0][1]);
    console.log(arrayFromText[1][0] + "=" + arrayFromText[1][1]);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what is exactly eval() function in javascript? The only I got online is it executes the argument.

Comment: eval(string) will execute the string as code. In this code it is taking the string from data attribute and transforming it in array. 

You can read more about eval function here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the brief explanation. But, from what I read online it is dangerous to put eval() on your code due to its vulnerability to be abused by hacker.

Comment: @BonifaciusSarumpaet you're right, moreover, in most cases eval has really poor performances compared to other solutions (here, `JSON.parse` is much more efficient for instance)

Answer (score -3):

If using PHP do in PHP:

```
$arr_test = ['A','C','E'];
$coded = json_encode($arr_test);
// paste coded in data-atribute
print '<div class="funPlus" data-arr_diensten="'. $coded . '"></div>';
```

The HTML on inspect looks like:

```
<div class="funPlus" data-arr_diensten="[&quot;A&quot;,&quot;C&quot;,&quot;E&quot;]"></div>
```

Now in javascript retrieve the array, but if it has only one value it returns as a string. So you have to test and fix this. If it is a string we have to remove the extra quotes. $(this) has to point to the object.

```
var arr_diensten = $(this).data("arr_diensten");
if (typeof arr_diensten == "string") arr_diensten = [arr_diensten.slice(1, -1)];
console.log(arr_diensten);
```