# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON parse error that I can't debug. Code below:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#confirmreset', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var action_url = $(this).attr("action");
    alert_box_register("Resetting password...");
    console.log(action_url);
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(postData);

    $.post(action_url, postData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        alert_box_register(obj.message);
    });
});
```

And the JSON:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "A temporary password has been emailed to you."
}
```

In Firefox the error is "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character", in Chrome it's "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token C "

Any ideas?

***EDIT: This works fine on my localhost setup. ***

Comment: That is valid JSON *as presented*, so I suspect that the *real* JSON data contains a character that is not making it across the translation.

Comment: How is the json being generated?

Comment: Where are you calling `JSON.parse`?

Comment: it happens within `$.parseJSON(data)`, but i'm sure you knew that.

Comment: Don't parse the json inside the callback. Instead, tell jquery that it is json. `$.post(action_url, postData, function(data){...}, "json")` If your success stops working, that means your server isn't returning valid json.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I assume that's jQuery formatting? This error is caught in jquery.min

Comment: @JasonP It's processed through a PHP script (http://www.php-login.net MVC v4 to be precise)

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, not sure I follow your syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412574/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-2-of-the-json)

Comment: Check using Chrome developer tools (Inspect element -> network) what really is the response. It could be that your server side script prints out an error message or something similar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to call `$.parseJSON` if the server is sending valid JSON as jQuery will parse it automatically when it retrieves the response.  I don't know the exact criteria, but if you set the `Content-type: application/json` header it *definitely* will.

Comment: Thanks, so would you propose just 'var obj = $(data);'

Comment: No, just `var obj = data`, or even `function (obj) {` -- basically `data` is ready for use immediately

Comment: This creates Object {status: "error", message: Array[1]}
 (index):241
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: @alias51 that means your server isn't returning valid json.

Comment: @KevinB Ok, thanks but when I lint the JSON in the question, it returns as valid?

Comment: Right, but that's probably not the only thing the server is returning.

Comment: ...so how would I debug this properly?

Comment: @KevinB (fyi, this works fine on a localhost server, which is odd)

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for answer, and this proved to be my problem as well. Trying to parse already parsed data. Since it is pre-paresed when usning json as type or getJSON as method.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by using single quotation marks (`'`) instead of double (`"`) for strings.

The [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires double quotation marks for strings.

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355724/1461850

Answer (score 0):

1. Only put these=>

   dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,