# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character on my json data

Tags: javascript, json

i haven't found response on differents post about that's problem ...

i call a servcie who returns a json data, the code works fine on localhot but don't work online...

my success method :

```
if (data !== null) {
    var _summoners = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var keys = Object.keys(_summoners);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
        $("." + keys[i]).text(_summoners[keys[i]]);
    };
}
```

and the data returned :

```
{
    "45260330": "SharkMister",
    "42215171": "Nietpopov",
    "40247365": "emaki",
    "49678659": "FakeThePump",
    "42127891": "Nutty Trickster",
    "45397483": "Enter Name Here1",
    "26589510": "pedrocsi",
    "23324155": "Abdi385",
    "46217784": "ExpliciitA",
    "37018042": "GabrikageBR"
}
```

i can't find my mistake, any idea ?

NB : i set the `dataType` on my ajax call to 'json'

and my returns headers is:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

And the exact error is :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character 
var _summoners  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

The returns type object is a string well formated...

Comment: Could it be that `data` is **already** an object (not a string containing JSON)?

Comment: With those headers I'd guess that jQuery has already parsed the data for you and that `data` is an object, not a string.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data)` show? Unless it says `string`, you shouldn't be parsing it.

Comment: @Felix i have a json object in my firebug console request but when i try to use data without convertion i have : TypeError: _summoners is not an object var keys = Object.keys(_summoners);

Comment: The *response* headers would be the relevant ones, not your `Accept` header. Please show those to us.

Comment: @Barmar yes, good, it's a string type !

Comment: @Ema.H: OK, if it's a string then please log it and post its exact value. The data you presented is valid JSON.

Comment: {"45260330":"SharkMister","42215171":"Nietpopov","40247365":"emaki","49678659":"FakeThePump","42127891":"Nutty Trickster","45397483":"Enter Name Here1","26589510":"pedrocsi","23324155":"Abdi385","46217784":"ExpliciitA","37018042":"GabrikageBR"} but maybe some\r ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824224/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i ve found a solution with EVAL ! I post it for someone with the same problem :

```
if (data !== null) {
    var _summoners = eval("("+data+")"); // $.parseJSON(data);
    var keys = Object.keys(_summoners);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
        $("." + keys[i]).text(_summoners[keys[i]]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery automatically parses the data for you when it can infer the data type and you haven't indicated otherwise (via the [`dataType` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). When `data` already is a JS object, calling `JSON.parse` on it will fail (stringifying the data to `JSON.parse("[object Object]")`). Try

```
var _summoners = data;
```

Comment: with only data i have this error : TypeError: _summoners is not an object
var keys = Object.keys(_summoners);

Comment: Can you show us the whole ajax call, please? What does `console.log(data)` give, what `console.log(typeof data)`?

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle may help: http://jsfiddle.net/uvp93/2/

Your data may be in JSON object form, rather than string form. `jQuery.parseJSON()` takes string form JSON and converts it to a respective JavaScript object.

Try this:

```
if (data !== null) {
    var _summoners = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
    var keys = Object.keys(_summoners);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        console.log(keys[i]);
        $("." + keys[i]).text(_summoners[keys[i]]);
    };
}
```

If your data is in object form, just perform a simple assignment: `_summoners = data`

Comment: Did you really just recommend to stringify the data only to parse it rightafter?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know what form the OP has his data in. I edited it to include the easier alternative.

Comment: For what form of data would it make a difference?

Comment: that's don't change anything... my problem is only on my web site not on my localhost... curious !