# JavaScript $.parseJSON error - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an error in Javascript

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
...n.now(),dc=/\?/;n.parseJSON=function(a){return JSON.parse(a+"")},n.parseXML=func...
```

And this is my JavaScript, which gets string from server response

```
complete: function(response) {
    var results = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
```

Error is in the second line because without that line there's no error)
My PHP script: (I use CodeIgniter)

```
    $str = json_encode($results);
    $this->output->set_output($str);
```

And an example of the message from server:

```
{"Thumb_image":"http:\/\/example.com\/img\/thumbs\/9b4138094cb32af906e32f9d033d4748.jpg","Big_image":"http:\/\/example.com\/img\/photos\/9b4138094cb32af906e32f9d033d4748.jpg","Error":""}
```

Help me please. Why this code is working wrong?

Comment: Nope, I don't buy it. `response.responseText` is not what you're telling us it is - console.log it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I can bet the user is using jQuery 1.9+ and the user is passing `undefined` to `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824224/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $str = json_encode($results);
 $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo $str;
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? How will it solve the problem? Please provide an **explanation** so that other readers can *learn*.

Comment: I can't use such function as header, because CodeIgniter doesn't allow me that. It writes in error log that headers were already sent. Maybe someone has ideas how can I do this by using CodeIgniter means?

Comment: This helped. Thank you. I simply had some more bugs