# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to append this div to another div , but it give me this error :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data

This is my javascript code:

```
var str = {'message': message,'text': text};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/reply",
    data: str,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        var respons = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        var type = respons.status
        if (type == 'success') {
            $("<div></div>").html(respons.message).appendTo("#messages");
        }
        else
        {
            toastr.error(respons.message)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Run it through jsonlint.com to validate it

Comment: When you throw your code into JSBin you immediately see that you have some syntax errors. I added a test API endpoint and a fake input so that you can play with it there: http://jsbin.com/sojibojetu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081701/i-keep-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o)

Comment: This is the 'problem' with jquery. In XMLHTTPRequest and Fetch API, we have to perform JSON.parse ourselves, so we are used to doing it; but in case of JQuery, the maker has done the parsing for us. So you simply need to drop the JSON.parse.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Simply change

`var respons = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

to

`var respons = response;`

**Explanation:**

If the configuration of your AJAX call is having `dataType: json` you'll get a JavaScript object so it's no longer necessary to use JSON.parse().

Comment: awesome. thank you very much ! in my case there no line like  `dataType: "json",` but result was same, i already data json, able to understand by js!

Comment: Impressive. Very good explanation. :)

Answer (score 23):

This is a hackish and unorthodox way of parsing JSON, but if you still want to use `JSON.parse()` from an AJAX call or simply on JSON that is already parsed and isn't a string, you can use `JSON.stringify()` inside it:

```
var respons = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: You are right. but i don't think there is a usecase for that.

Comment: I was debug my error by this statement. 
var respons = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: Why would we want that? Removing JSON.parse altogether is the correct solution.

Comment: @DanielWu As time has passed, I agree there isn't much applicability to my solution. Maybe a better answer would be writing a helper method that detects whether the JSON is an object or string, then returning the parsed JSON.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is you're not parsing a string, you're parsing an already parsed object.

Answer (score 2):

the values in your object seem to be undefined.
change
`var str = {'message': message,'text': text};` to
`var str = {message: 'message',text: 'text'};`