# jQuery .ajax Call Returns JSON ParseError Even Thought JSON Appears to be Correct?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm getting a ParseError even though my JSON validates on jsonlint.com.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                  
    success: function (data) {
        var a = 'breakpoint here doesn't activate';
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        var b = 'code execution stops at a breakpoint here.';
    }
});
```

Here is the PHP code that is being called:

```
function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName) {
    $testData[0] = 'testing123';
    $encodedData = json_encode($testData);
    echo $encodedData;
    return;
}
```

This comes back to a breakpoint set in the error: function of my .ajax call. Parameter Y is set to "parseerror", and x.responseText =

```
["testing123"]
```

I've been looking into this for hours so far. I've looked at many relevant StackOverflow posts, but none have solutions that work in this case.

How can I get a success response from this .ajax call?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info.

Comment: `var a = 'breakpoint here doesn't activate';` should be `var a = 'breakpoint here doesn\'t activate';`

Comment: Did you found "parseerror" in Mozilla's console?

Comment: @Shaunuk, good point. I have the same results with `var a = 'breakpoint here does not activate';`

Comment: @minspace, I am using the Safari console, and that is where I see the "parserror".

Comment: check ..response headers should have "application/json"

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: @minspace, how do I check the response headers?

Comment: @Shaunak, yes, I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: fine.. mention it in tag of your question..

Comment: Instead of `echo $encodedData; return;` try `return $encodedData;` OR just leave it as `echo $encodedData;` and remove `return;`.

Comment: @Shaunuk, I tried both per your instructions but got the same error.

Comment: @VikR, ok.. Last possible solution from me.. change `function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName)` to `function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName='')` as you are sending blank data, so parameter passed should be optional...

Comment: I just looked at the z param in the Safari console, and found this: `"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'JSON.parse(a+"")')"` How could that be happening? sourceURL is `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`. Call stack is `"parseJSON@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:5314
uc@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:7334
x@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:18903
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:14578"`

Comment: I dont know about Safari. But in mozilla i am sure you will get pin to pin details of raw request and raw response ... In that you should get application/json in your response headers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing visibly wrong with your code, and it works fine when I try it on my local machine.  However, your comment above is a big clue:

> I just looked at the z param in the Safari console, and found this:"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'JSON.parse(a+"")')" How could that be happening?

It could happen if some code somewhere uses "JSON" as a global variable name, hiding the built-in window.JSON object.

Comment: you solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!!  The last time I used this project was with an older version of jQuery, and I was including a JSON.js library.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!! I wish I could upvote your answer about 1500 times!

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone here who helped track it down!

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
 $.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',                  
    success: function (data) {
        var a = 'breakpoint here doesn\'t activate';
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        var b = 'code execution stops at a breakpoint here.';
    }
});
```

and in your PHP CODE Paste this code.

```
function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName) {
    $testData[0] = 'testing123';
    $encodedData = $testData;
    echo json_encode($encodedData);
    exit;
}
```

May be after digging more in your code I assume that in your PHP code you were not passing data properly. Please use exit or die method to pass data back to ajax. Please check.

Comment: using the code you provided, I still have the error.

Comment: What about your data in ajax request ? Are you sending proper data to server ?

Comment: for this test I have tried to reduce everything to a bare minimum. As far as I know, I am sending no data to the server. `data: {}` If there is something else to check along these lines, please let me know.

Comment: Please see my updated code and without checking your complete code I can't find any bugs. Please share your complete code if you can.

Comment: Here is the complete code—I have to use two comments to fit it in: `function testAjax()
{
    var path = "http://" + theHostname + "/welcome/getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax/tempjob";

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
`

Comment: `success: function (data) {
            //Use one from both
            var a = 'breakpoint here doesn\'t activate';
            var a1 = 'breakpoint here does not activate';
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            var b = 'code execution stops at a breakpoint here.';
        }
    });


$(document).ready(function ()
{
    testAjax();
});`

Answer (score 1):

Check for Notice or Warning in your php code, if their is any then remove that and then try. Hop this will help you.

Comment: There are no errors or warning in the php code or php errors log file.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows either single or double quotes for strings, but JSON *only* allows double quotes. See http://www.json.org/

See also [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14355655/54323)

Answer (score 1):

Just Use

```
function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName) {
   $testData[0] = 'testing123';
   echo json_encode($testData);
}
```

Then in your AJAX you can do

```
$.ajax({
 url: path,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json'
 success: function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //DO YOUR STUFF          
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: Good thought. But in practice I need to return a very large array of arrays. And per my discovery noted in a comment above, the whole issue seems to be that JSON.parse isn't callable. `"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'JSON.parse(a+"")')`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with the below code,

    function getAllAnswersToHitViaAjax($theJobName) {
    $testData[0] = 'testing123';
    echo json_encode($testData);
    die();
    }

    $.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result);
    }
    });
```