# saving the cppheaderparser output as valid json

Tags: json, python-2.7

the python program 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppheaderparser/
can parse a c++ header file and store the info (about classes etc) in a python dictionary.

Using the included example program readSampleClass.py and

```
data_string = ( repr(cppHeader) )
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dumps(data_string,outfile)
```

it saved the output but it is not valid json as
it uses single, not double quotes and key part is not quoted.

sample of output: (reduced)

```
{'enums': [], 'variables': [], 'classes': 
    {'SampleClass': 
        {'inherits': [], 'line_number': 8, 'declaration_method': 'class', 'typedefs': 
            {'public': [], 'private': [], 'protected': []
            }, 'abstract': False, 'parent': None,'parent': None, 'reference': 0, 'constant': 0, 'aliases': [], 'raw_type': 'void', 'typedef': None, 'mutable': False
        }], 'virtual': False, 'rtnType': 'int', 'returns_class': False, 'name': 'anotherFreeFunction', 'constructor': False, 'inline': False, 'returns_pointer': 0, 'defined': False
     }]
}
```

so the question is:

How can I make it use double quotes and not single and how can I also make it quote the value part. Like False in sample.

I assume is possible as the creator of cppheaderparser wrote
about json.dumps(repr(cppHeader))
https://twitter.com/senexcanis/status/559444754166198272

Why use the json lib if its not valid jason?
That said I have never used python before and it might just not work as i think.

-update-

After some json doc reading, i gave up on json.dump as it seems to do nothing to the output in this case. 
I ended up doing

```
data_string = ( repr(cppHeader) )
data_string = string.replace(data_string,'\'', '\"')
data_string = string.replace(data_string,'False', '\"False\"')
data_string = string.replace(data_string,'True', '\"True\"')
data_string = string.replace(data_string,'None', '\"None\"')
data_string = string.replace(data_string,'...', '')
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write (data_string)
```

which give valid json - at least for my test c++ headers.

-update 2-
The creator of cppheaderparse just released a new 2.6 version where its possible to write `CppHeaderParser.CppHeader("yourHeader.h").toJSON()` to save as json.

Comment: Huh? json does use single quotes, at least for whatever tests I ran

Comment: Reading the specs at http://www.json.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote suggest it does NOT.

Comment: The [JSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) encoder does the right thing, is what I meant, for whatever tests and validators I put the output through.

Comment: Oh, using the output of cppheaderparser ?

Comment: Just use update #2.. .toJSON is bound to do the right thing.