# Parse string with double qoute breaks

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

My question is related to this question [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote).
There are many topics on this issue, but I still don't know clean solution.

I dont have Jquery, and I am working in TypeScript (not JavaScript). But everythink else is same.

My question is: What if I have string with double qoute ?

How to resolve this problem ?
Is there way to convert this in valid string type?

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

I will get error if json string is with double qoute.

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token**

Whole code is:

```
fs.readFile(templatePath, 'utf8', (err: Error, data: Object) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(500);
    }

    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        res.json(obj);
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(500);
    }
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You may try this `JSON.stringify(jobj)` that will automatically convert the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @SASIKUMARS have you even read the question? He is getting his data from a File dude...

Comment: Yes what ever the source it might be, that wont be a concern. @ B. Kemmer

Comment: @SASIKUMARS he doesn't have an JSON-Object, so he can't use JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before storing your string into JSON replace all instances of " with \"

```
var str='hello "Rajat Bhardwaj"';
str=str.replace(/"/g,'\\"');
// Now push it into JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all occurences of a single quote in your string. You can do this by simply using the **[String.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)** function.

You could write a single function which is reusable if you need it elsewhere like that:

```
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

and call it like that:

```
var str = replaceAll("'", "\"", data);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

For more informations, check this answer: [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes with a backslash `\"blah blah \"` or write your custom sanitizer.

```
data = '{\"text\": \"This is json string with double quotes\"}' .
```

A backslash in front of a double quote makes it part of a string and not a special character. This is called escaping a character.

Comment: How to escape quotes? Can you write example?

Comment: Assume your `data = '{\"text\":  \"This is json string with double quotes\"}'` . Backslash in front of a double quote makes it part of a string and not a special character.