# Value string(2) of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, laravel-5, android-volley

I'm trying to connect my Android app to my Laravel API and I'm receiving the following error.

```
Value string(2) of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

after running my volley request. The request goes trough, but I cannot check for status of the request because it always returns an error.

I believe it is because I'm returning a JSON Array in my Laravel app.

This is my Laravel's app response on success

```
return Response::json(array(
                                'status'  => 'ok',
                                'message'  => 'success',
                        ));
```

And this is my Volley request on Android

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Log.d("sendOrderToServer", "called");
        Log.d("json obj", order.toString());


        JsonObjectRequest jsor = new JsonObjectRequest(MainActivity.ADD_ORDER, order, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("response", response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error34", error.toString());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("charset", "utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsor);
```

How could I do this properly without manually parsing a string and making a string request in Android Volley library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a var_dump in my event' __construct for debugging purposes and I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using " (double quote) instead ' (single quote)

JSON "doesn't like" single quote, double quote is standard:

```
return Response::json(array(
                                "status"  => "ok",
                                "message"  => "success",
                        ));
```

See on SO: [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote)

Comment: Thank you, will change it. I found out what was the issue, I had a Laravel event being created before the return, and it was returnin the event's broadcastOn return value as well, so the response was a string + json and that's why Volley was failing.