# compare two json objects and remove the element and then compare resultant json to other json file

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

Python newbie:

Default.json

```
   {
"name": {
 "provide": ""
},
"test": {
  "Fail": {
    "centers": None,
    "Nearest": 0
  },
  "far": "",
  "Meta": null,
  "Only": false,
  "Tags": null
 },
"Session": "",
"conf": {
  "check": "",
  "Reg": ""
 },
"Token": ""
```

}

```
Remote.json

 [ {
  'name': {
  'provide': ''
   },
  'Name': 'abc',
  'test': {
    'Service': 'redis',
    'Tags': [
      'stage'
     ],
    'Fail': {
      'centers': None,
      'Nearest': 3
     },
     'Only': false,
     'far': '',
     'Meta': null
    },
   'Token': '',
   'Session': '',

   'conf': {
     'Reg': '',
     'check': 'name_prefix_match'
    },
} ]
```

I have a **default.json**  and **remote .json** .Task I am trying to achieve is *remove all the json elements* from the **remote.json** for whom the values of **remote.json** matches with the **default.json**.For example since the key,value of **name:{provider=""}** from *default.json* matches the **name:{provider=""}** from **remote.json**.It should get removed from **remote.json**

```
with open(remote.json) as f:
 with open(default.json) as m:
   file=json.load(f)
   default=json.load(m)
   for i in xrange(len(file)):
     for key,value in default.items():
        #default[key]=value
      #a=filter(lambda x: x[""],file.keys())
```

1.I am not getting the idea here how to get key, value from *default* and compare it with *file*?Any help would be appreciated.

The reason I need to remove element from remote.json is because I need to compare the resultant json with other json file "local.json".If i dont' remove the key ,values with value "" or null or None then the comparison between remote.json and local.json would never be equal.

2.Is there any better way of going for this problem?

local.json

```
{ 
  "Name": "",
  "conf": {
   "check": "name_prefix_match",
  },
  "test": {
    "Service": "redis",
    "Fail": {
     "Near": 3
   },
  "Tags": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: btw your JSON is invalid: `None` is not `null` and `False` is not `false`

Comment: sub-dictionaries are also should be filtered?

Comment: please, add example of filtered remote JSON

Comment: added fixes assuming filtering sub-dictionaries like `'test'` in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with JSON examples because of `None` & `False` are not valid JSON objects (and so are [single-quoted string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355724/5997596)), so let's pretend that we've already parsed files and got something like

```py
default_json = {
    "name": {
        "provide": ""
    },
    "test": {
        "Fail": {
            "centers": None,
            "Nearest": 0
        },
        "far": "",
        "Meta": None,
        "Only": False,
        "Tags": None
    },
    "Session": "",
    "conf": {
        "check": "",
        "Reg": ""
    },
    "Token": ""
}

remote_json = [{
    "name": {
        "provide": ""
    },
    "Name": "abc",
    "test": {
        "Service": "redis",
        "Tags": [
            "stage"
        ],
        "Fail": {
            "centers": None,
            "Nearest": 3
        },
        "Only": False,
        "far": "",
        "Meta": None
    },
    "Token": "",
    "Session": "",

    "conf": {
        "Reg": "",
        "check": "name_prefix_match"
    },
}]
```

Assuming that `remote.json` is the list of dictionaries & each one of them should be filtered out using `default.json`:

```py
filtered_remote_json = [dict(item
                             for item in dictionary.items()
                             if item not in default_json.items())
                        for dictionary in remote_json]
```

will give us

```
filtered_remote_json == [{"Name": "abc",
                          "test": {"Service": "redis", "Tags": ["stage"],
                                   "Fail": {"centers": None,
                                            "Nearest": 3}, "Only": False,
                                   "far": "", "Meta": None},
                          "conf": {"Reg": "",
                                   "check": "name_prefix_match"}}]
```

## EDIT

if we need to filter sub-dictionaries as well, then next a bit nasty utility function should help

```py
def filter_defaults(json_object, default_json_object):
    result = {}
    for key, value in json_object.items():
        try:
            default_value = default_json_object[key]
        except KeyError:
            # key not in defaults, adding to result
            result[key] = value
            continue

        # we need to process sub-dictionaries as well
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value = filter_defaults(value, default_value)
            # we are not interested in empty filtered sub-dictionaries
            if not value:
                continue
        # value should differ from default
        elif value == default_value:
            continue

        result[key] = value

    return result
```

then just write

```
filtered_remote_json = [filter_defaults(dictionary, default_json)
                        for dictionary in remote_json]
```

this will give us

```py
filtered_remote_json == [{"Name": "abc",
                          "test": {"Service": "redis", "Tags": ["stage"],
                                   "Fail": {"Nearest": 3}},
                          "conf": {"check": "name_prefix_match"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer .One thing that the filtered_remote_json shouldn't have the keys for which value in None or False or "" in it.How should i refactor the list comprehension for that?

Comment: @immrsteel: so you need to filter subdictionaries as well?