# How do I validate multiple schema using Json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have following scenario of incoming messages from different devices to processing unit which shall process the messages based on message type.

1. Messages with following Schema definition for `hobbies`, say `schema-hobbies`

   ```
   JSchema hobbiesSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
                  'type': 'object',
                  'properties': {
                  'name': {'type':'string'},
                  'hobbies': {
                     'type': 'array',
                     'items': {'type':'string'}
                  }}}");
   ```
2. Messages with following Schema definition for `countries`, say `schema-countries`

   ```
   JSchema countriesSchema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
                  'type': 'object',
                  'properties': {
                  'name': {'type':'string'},
                  'countries': {
                     'type': 'array',
                     'items': {'type':'string'}
                  }}}");
   ```
3. Messages which do not follow any of above `Schema` definitions

Now, I am able to validate the `hobbies` messages as follow

```
    JObject hobbies = JObject.Parse(@"{
    'name': 'James',
    'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
    }");

    IList<string> errorMessages;
    bool valid = hobbies.IsValid(hobbiesSchema , out errorMessages);

    Console.WriteLine(valid);
```

I shall able to merge both schema and **validate different incoming messages**. How can I do that?

For example:

If message Json is,

```
    {
    'name': 'James',
    'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
    }
```

Output shall be: `True`

If message Json is,

```
    {
    'name': 'James',
    'countries': ['India', 'Australia']
    }
```

Output shall be: `True`

If message Json is,

```
    {
    'Time': '03:45 AM',
    'heartbeats': ['30', '45']
    }
```

Output shall be: `False`

Note:

1. Sample schema used in this question is just for reference. Real schema is very complex.

Comment: Only double quotes are allowed. All the examples are invalid json.

Comment: @radarbob you are wrong. This works like charm. example taken from Json.net site. question is about how to merge and json provided here is just a sample example.

Comment: I just get that "uh-oh" sense because of unpleasant experience passing text-based defined format data that violates the specification. The more "nodes" sharing corrupt formatting the harder it is to ever correct and made worse by independently evolving parsing. Y'all be careful out there.

Comment: Okay. Then please share the best practices or sample which resolves these issues. it helps

Comment: @kudlatiger - your question is answered on the same page you took your samples from (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm) *Json.NET supports the JSON Schema standard via the JsonSchema and JsonValidatingReader classes. It sits under the Newtonsoft.Json.Schema namespace.* - rather than merging the schemas into an uber schema, just have two validation steps in your validation component.

Comment: Also, you should not really use single quotes, even though it works with some parsers. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355724/569662