# Unmarshaling json rawdata from redash in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I got a response from redash as follows:

```
{'PP_DOM': '{"DEFAULT":100}',....................., 'Myst':'["a","b","c","d"]',
```

- I want to unmarshal `"myst"` key's value as a list in golang.I am newbie here.

Comment: [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package is your friend here. When you have some code and trouble, post it here so we can assist you further.

Comment: Please post the complete response

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshall into map[string]interface{} if you have an unknown data structure to explore it. you then may later want to define a struct which maps to the data properly. So to get started, use something like this:

```golang
    var jsonData = []byte(`{"PP_DOM": {"DEFAULT":100},"Myst":["a","b","c","d"]}`)
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("json: error decoding", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Myst:%+v", data["Myst"])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/V5GBtLH6oLs

Your json doesn't appear to be [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote), better to post what you have tried instead, which should at least involve valid json.

You should take a look at the docs for the json pkg, in particular the [examples](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal).