# JSON.parse label data from string var

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have 2 var below to update datasets and labels of my chart.

```
function updateChart(){

   var newdatasets= "[10, 20, 30, 40]";
   var newlabels= "['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']";

   myChart.data.datasets[0].data = JSON.parse(newdatasets); //this work
   myChart.data.labels = JSON.parse(newlabels);             //this does not work
}
```

Why JSON.parse work with `newdatasets` but wont work with `newlabels`? The `JSON.parse(newdatasets)` updated the chart datasets successfully but `JSON.parse(newlabels)` fail to update chart labels. What can I do to fix this?

Dont ask me to change the var value to `['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']` without the `"`. I know this will work but I want the chart to change from that kind of var value.

Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newlabels` is having wrong JSON string format. Let change `'` with `"` with escape.

This will work:

```js
var newlabels= "[\"label1\", \"label2\", \"label3\", \"label4\"]";
myChart.data.labels = JSON.parse(newlabels);
```

The variable `newdatasets` works with `JSON.parse` because its elements are number.

Comment: For this purpose you do not even need to escape you could simply use ````var newlabels= '["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"]';````

Answer (score 2):

To be valid JSON, [you need double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote#:%7E:text=As%20per%20the%20API%20documentation,%2C%20single%20quotes%20aren%27t.&text=Go%20to%20www.Jsonlint.com,json%20is%20standard%20json%20format.). So the code below works.

Both examples work. You just need double quotes as part of the string itself.

```js
var newlabels2= '["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"]';
console.log(JSON.parse(newlabels2)); 

var newlabels3= "[\"label1\", \"label2\", \"label3\", \"label4\"]";
console.log(JSON.parse(newlabels3));
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON does not support single quotes, so this code:

```js
 var newlabels= "['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4']";
```

Becomes this:

```js
 var newlabels= '["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"]';
```