# Retrieve Values using jQuery of JSON Data after JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hope things are going well.

I'm hoping to use jQuery to retrieve values from a JSON string. I'm currently using the following xmlHTTPrequest to retrieve the data and JSON.stringify the responseText.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();        
  xhr.open("GET", "apiary url goes here");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.responseText));                        
      data = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

It gives me a response such as this:

```
[{
    "id_profile": 1, 
    "name": "John"
    "id" : "894JF84JF39"
},
{
    "id_profile": 2, 
    "name": "Sally"
    "id" : "894JF231239"
}]
```

I was attempting to the parse.JSON(); this data to turn it into a JSON object until I came across the following question/answer [JSON.parse unexpected character error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error) . That question indicated that the data was already parsed. I was getting an error using `parseJSON(data)`. My goal is to use jQuery to retrieve values of the fields, but the value of `data[0]` returns the string character or "[" in this specific case. I also attempted to retrieve information use `data.id_profile` and `data[0].id_profile` but this came back "undefined" (obviously "[" doesn't have any properties).

In the form that the JSON is returned as, what would be the effective method of retrieving the value of the "id_profile" key (or is even considered a key currently)? Can I apply a function to this data variable to turn it into a true JSON object notation or can I somehow use this existing format to get the values?

Update #1

It seems the data being returned has new line characters and white space and may be preventing preventing `JSON.parse();` or `parseJSON();` from returning anything other than Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`. This seems in line with jquery parseJSON(); documentation. What javascript code could I use to replace the newline characters, empty space, and "\" characters?

```
{\n    \"id_artist\": 1, \n    \"name\": \"John\"\n    \"id\" : \"{\n    \"id_artist_profile\": 1, \n    \"public_nick_name\": \"Kayla\"\n    \"id_artist\" : \"894JF84JF39R90FM\",\n\",\n.............
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the inbuilt function rather than `$.ajax()`?

Comment: You are converting the response headers to JSON, not the response text, so that parts seems irrelevant. Is it actually the response text that you tried to parse? What's your code for that?

Comment: The JSON.stringify(); is currently wrapped around the 'this.responseText'. Wouldn't that stringify that portion as well? This XMLHTTPRequest is from and Apiary API, copied exactly from what they suggest for a javascript GET request. I may try an $.ajax() request instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some misplaced commas in your response and should be single quotes on the outside...

```
"[{"key":"value"}]" will cause parsing to break..
'[{"key":"value"}]' will work as expected

'[{
  "id_profile": 1, 
  "name": "John", //comma here..
  "id" : "894JF84JF39" // no comma here,
},
{
  "id_profile": 2, 
  "name": "Sally", //comma here
  "id" : "894JF231239" //no comma here,
}]'
```

here is a fiddle to demonstrate... http://jsfiddle.net/e8Arg/

UPDATE: as far as fixing the response (quotes,commas) that will be easiest to do on the server that returns the response, otherwise, you'll need to do some replacing once you get the response back, before trying to convert to json

Comment: The double quotes actually came from copying from console and I removed some of the data elements from each json element for demonstration purposes. I'll try JSON.parse(); instead and see if that works for me. Thanks!