# Loop through list returned with JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

hi i'm new to MVC and Here is my problem...
i'm sending something like below list to my view with " return JSON(); "

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> Foodlist = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {         
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Pitzza",Value="1"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Sandwich",Value="2"},
        new SelectListItem() {Text = "Other",Value="3"}
    };
```

and  i receive it with an ajax call.

then in my view i want to use the value of "Text" and "Value" property(in the same ajax call)...but i can't .
i tried to alert "data.property" or using "$.each" and "for" loop but i got nowhere with it.

update :

```
    $.ajax({
                Type: "Post",
                url: "@Url.Action("Foodselector", "Order")",
                contenttype: "application/json ; charset=UTF-8",
                datatype: "JSON",
                data: { TypeID: $("#SelectedFoodType").val() },
                complete:
                    function (data) {

                       // Here i wana use the list//
                    }                    
                });
```

here is action :

```
    public ActionResult Foodselector(int TypeID)
    {
        if (TypeID == 1)
        {
            return Json(Food.ViewModel.OrderViewModel.Foodlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if(TypeID == 2)
        {
            return Json(Food.ViewModel.OrderViewModel.Drinklist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        if (TypeID == 3)
        {
            return Json(Food.ViewModel.OrderViewModel.Dessertlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(3,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: use data.Text and data.Value inside $.each()

Comment: please share the code that parses the JSON response, otherwise it's hard to guess what you're not doing right. thanks!

Comment: i did use "data.Text and data.Value inside $.each()" bu it  just didnt work.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: it shows : undefined

Comment: Show the FoodSelector action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- don't use `complete` function if you want to catch the Error , you need to use `success` and `error` methods

check this

```
 $.ajax({
                Type: "Post",
                url: "@Url.Action("Foodselector", "Order")",
                contenttype: "application/json ; charset=UTF-8",
                datatype: "JSON",
                data: { TypeID: $("#SelectedFoodType").val() },
                complete:
                    function (data) {

                           alert('complete');

                    },
                success: function(data){  

                    alert('success');

                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

                    alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 

                }                     
                });
```

now you are able to know what is the Error and where its come from

Comment: okay then the problem is not from JS , the problem from server response can you post the output here ? what is `data` return from server ?

Comment: this is the response :
[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Pitzza","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Sandwich","Value":"2"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Other","Value":"3"}]

Comment: so good, ok then add this inside to use the response as Json code , `var response = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: can u explain more....still got nothing....
and when i alert response i get a error in firebug that ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: ok `data` has the Json but you can't use it as json , for example `alert(response[0].Text); ` to be abel to use this Json string as Json you have to Parse it like this , `var response = JSON.parse(data);` now you can do this , `alert( response[0].Text);`

Comment: now i get this error :
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error
says its because it is already parsed

Comment: it says :
TypeError: data[0] is undefined

Comment: you tried it on both success and complete ? try to do this alert(data.length);

Comment: well in Success it return 3 for length but in complete it return nothing.
and as for parse in success and complete both, it says :
 JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: ok i need u to remove `complete` function keep only success and error , and alert this inside `success : function(data){ alert( data[0].Text);    }`

Comment: oh...sweet lord ....finally.....its working , thank u man ..thank u so much..i have been stock on this for a week ....so what do you think was the problem??? Complete?

Comment: you are using complete , and calling data , complete function dose not return any data only success and error return's with data :)