# Odoo: JSON: Inherit view, hide edit button conditionally

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xpath, odoo

I'm trying to hide the edit button in the bill of material form in Odoo, dependent on the state of a boolean.

I managed to remove the edit button permanent with the code below:

```
<xpath expr="//form[@string='Bill of Material']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Now I tried to make it conditional with a boolean like this:

```
<xpath expr="//form[@string='Bill of Material']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="edit">true:realman==True;false:realman==False;</attribute>
</xpath>
```

This gives error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

When I looked up the javascript file, I've found this is the code to handle the edit attribute:

```js
/**
 * Return whether the user can perform the action ('create', 'edit', 'delete') in this view.
 * An action is disabled by setting the corresponding attribute in the view's main element,
 * like: <form string="" create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
 */
is_action_enabled: function(action) {
    var attrs = this.fields_view.arch.attrs;
    return (action in attrs) ? JSON.parse(attrs[action]) : true;
},
```

I suppose I need to get `false` in that `var attrs` when the boolean `realman` in my form is `False`?

I've already tried to write it in curly brackets like the answer in this question: [JSON.parse unexpected character error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error)

That gave me errors too.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix this? Is this just a syntax error or are there more problems?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully solved a similar issue by using field_view_get, but only if "realman" is passed into context

```python
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = models.Model.fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    realman = context.get('realman', True)
    if not realman and view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for t in doc.xpath("//form[@string='Bill of Material']"):
            t.attrib['edit'] = 'false'
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

if realman is instead a field and you need to enable/disable the edit button, then I'm afraid it is just not possible. AFAIK.

Comment: Just remember to import etree from lxml!

Answer (score 0):

As [Alessandro Ruffolo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908365/2617691) stated his solution doesn't work for buttons/actions depending on model's field. I have written solution in Javascript for that. It works in ODOO 10 (should in 9 also but I haven't tested it).

Example is checking on model's field "state". If it has value "noEditable" edit and delete buttons would hide. It isn't enough to overwrite is_action_enabled because ODOO is calling the method when there is no datarecord loaded yet. Therefore it's needed to check it again after methods do_show and reload.

```
// modify default form view for custom model my.custom.model
odoo.define('my.custom_model_form', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var FormView = require('web.FormView');

    FormView.include({
        is_action_enabled: function(action) {
            if (this.model == "my.custom.model" && this.datarecord && this.datarecord.state == "noEditable" &&
                (action == 'delete' || action == 'edit')) {
                // don't allow edit nor delete
                return false;
            }
            // call default is_action_enabled method
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        deleteItem: null,
        deleteItemIdx: null,
        deleteItemShown: true,
        reinit_actions: function() {
            // apply for my custom model only
            if (this.model == "my.custom.model") {
                // hide/show edit button
                if (this.is_action_enabled('edit')) {
                    this.$buttons.find(".o_form_button_edit").show();
                } else {
                    this.$buttons.find(".o_form_button_edit").hide();
                }

                // find delete item in sidebar's items
                if (!this.deleteItem) {
                    // form view is adding it to "other"
                    if (this.sidebar && this.sidebar.items && this.sidebar.items.other) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.sidebar.items.other.length; i++) {
                            // on_button_delete is used as callback for delete button
                            // it's ugly way to find out which one is delete button, haven't found better way
                            if (this.sidebar.items.other[i].callback == this.on_button_delete) {
                                this.deleteItem = this.sidebar.items.other[i];
                                this.deleteItemIdx = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // hide/show delete button
                if (this.is_action_enabled('delete')) {
                    if (!this.deleteItemShown) {
                        this.deleteItemShown = true;
                        // add delete item to sidebar's items
                        this.sidebar.items.other.splice(this.deleteItemIdx, 0, this.deleteItem);
                    }
                } else
                if (this.deleteItemShown) {
                    this.deleteItemShown = false;
                    // remove delete item from sidebar's items
                    this.sidebar.items.other.splice(this.deleteItemIdx, 1);
                }
            }
        },
        reload: function() {
            var self = this;
            // run reinit_actions after reload finish
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments).done(function() {
                 self.reinit_actions();
            });
        },
        do_show: function() {
            var self = this;
            // run reinit_actions after do_show finish
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments).done(function() {
                 self.reinit_actions();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a solution with a computed field makes things simpler for these cases.

You can inherit the bill of material form and override it. Point the invisible condition to a computed field where you'll create your validation. Note that is necessary to add your computed field to the form, even though hiding it.

```
<xpath expr="//form[@string='Bill of Material']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">
        {'invisible': [('show_bm_button', '=', False)]}
    </attribute>
    <field name="show_bm_button" invisible="1"/>
</xpath>
```

Then override the object in python and add the new computed field.

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    show_bm_button = fields.Boolean(
            compute='_compute_show_bm_button', 
            readonly=False, store=False
        )

    # @api.depends('realman') #Just as a sample, if you have this field in this Model
    def _compute_show_bm_button(self):
        for record in self:
            realman = self._context.get('realman') or True
            if realman:
                record.show_bm_button = True
            else:
                record.show_bm_button = False
```