# Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: java, json, rest, jsp, servlets

I've just tried to calling `index.jsp` which sends a json to my rest project with http POST.

But it throws me this error: 
I can't figure out where is the issue
Any tip? I haven't idea for this.

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path [/HibernateTutorialWeb] threw exception [org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
> at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@24097548; line: 1, column: 2]] with root cause
> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
> at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@24097548; line: 1, column: 2]
> at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1213)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:375)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:1536)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:432)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:318)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2168)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2106)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
> at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
> at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
> at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Send jSon - put method</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    //var people = {"address": "Address 12", "name": "twelve", "id": 12,"surname": "twelve"};
    var people={"address": "hello"};
    function sendobject(){
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/HibernateTutorialWeb/rest/person/post",
            data: people,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){alert(data);},
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
      });
    }
    </script>
        <input type="button" onclick="sendobject()" value="invia"> </input>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</<html>
```

**PersonService . java**

```
package com.ws.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import com.dao.*;
import com.model.*;

@Path("/person")
public class PersonService {

    // try hello data
    // http://localhost:8080/HibernateTutorialWeb/rest/person/hello/mario
    @GET
    @Path("/hello/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Jersey say hello : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    // http://localhost:8080/HibernateTutorialWeb/rest/person/2
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getPersonById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return new PersonDao().getPersonById(id);
        // error for type of response incorrect
        /*
         * public ResponseBuilder getPersonById(@PathParam("id") int id){
         * PersonDao pDao = new PersonDao (); if(pDao.getPersonById(id) != null)
         * {return Response.status(200).entity(new
         * PersonDao().getPersonById(id));} else{ return
         * Response.status(200).entity("Utente id: "+ id + ", Rimosso"); }
         */
    }

    // //http://localhost:8080/HibernateTutorialWeb/rest/person/getAllJson
    @GET
    @Path("/getAllJson")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Person> getAllJson() {
        return new PersonDao().getAllPerson();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/xml/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Person getPersonByIdXML(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return new PersonDao().getPersonById(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUtenteJSON(Person person) {
        new PersonDao().saveOrUpdate(person);
        String result = "Person saved : " + person;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateUtente(Person person) {
        if (person.getId() != 0) {
            new PersonDao().saveOrUpdate(person);
            return Response.ok(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity("Specificare l'id dell'utente").build();
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response removePerson(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        new PersonDao().deletePerson(id);
        return Response.status(200).entity("Utente id: " + id + ", Rimosso")
                .build();
    }

}
```

**PersonDao.java**

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.model.Person;
import com.util.SessionFactoryUtil;

public class PersonDao {

    public void saveOrUpdate(Person person) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            if (person.getId() != 0) {
                //if exists update obj
                session.update(person);
            } else {
                session.save(person);
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void deletePerson(int id) {
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            Person person = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
            
            System.out.println("Deleted person :"+person.toString());
            
            session.delete(person);
            
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            people = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
            
            //session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (trns != null) {
                trns.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("People list : \n");
        for(int i=0;i<people.size();i++){
            System.out.println(people.get(i));
        }
        return people;
    }

    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        Person person = null;
        Transaction trns = null;
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            trns = session.beginTransaction();
            String queryString = "FROM Person WHERE id = :id";
            Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
            query.setInteger("id", id);
            person = (Person) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
        return person;
    }

}
```

**Updated :**
on index.jsp

```
var people = JSON.parse({"address": "Indirizzo 12", "name": "dodici", "id": 12,"surname": "dodici"});
```

Now the error is this :

```
    HTTP Status 500 - java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

type Exception report

message java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2173)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2106)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1004)
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: which line of code throws the error?

Comment: @AbtPst now i add the complete error !

Comment: ok, can you see which line in your java code is causing the exception? i cant seem to find out. basically which is the line of code where you are reading the data from JSP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.parse unexpected character error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524933/json-parse-unexpected-character-error)

Comment: is not a duplicate of JSON.parse, i've tried also the solution in that post but doesn't work. @JavaHD

Comment: @AbtPst I think the error actually outside Dhn's own code, in a conversion routine triggered by `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Comment: It would help to see the actual data produced by that JQuery AJAX request.

Comment: if u tell me how i can do it, i show it @JiriTousek

Comment: Use Firebug (should work with all major browsers), there should be a "Net" tab in it that allows you to see the request when you trigger the action in the website.

Comment: here is the pic [http://i.imgur.com/ItRFxbY.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by me,

There was an error on my jsp.
I was checking if it's a new user from the id.

Backend

```
if (person.getId() != 0) {
     //if exists update obj
     session.update(person);
} else {
     session.save(person);
}
```

Jsp:

```
var people = JSON.stringify
(eval({"address": "Indirizzo 12", "name": "twelve", "id": 12, "surname": "twelve"}));
```

So with the `Id`, the dao try to update a record inexistent on db, and this is the cause of the error.

Now thy is my `people` var in jsp :

```
var people = 
JSON.stringify(eval({"address": "Indirizzo 12", "name": "twelve","surname": "twelve"}));
```

It works good.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the `Object` to `JSON` line:

```
var people={"address": "ciao"};
```

To:

```
var people=JSON.stringify(eval({"address": "ciao"}));
```

Make sure that `Person` class has the same param constructor you passing to it.

---

*According to your image stack trace exception in the comment*, The error occurs in the `Hibernate` with Exception [StaleStateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html) which means:

> Thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating
>   that the Session contained stale data (when using long transactions
>   with versioning). Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that
>   does not exist

1. This can be resolved by updating the object from database like refresh method in hibernate and then commit will persist the object in databse.
2. You can use merge method and commit, but here you will override the current data.
3. Using lock can also be resolved to change the state.

Comment: see my updated comment on post : 

var people = JSON.parse({"address": "Indirizzo 12", "name": "dodici", "id": 12,"surname": "dodici"});

Comment: `JSON.parse` (you still passing object) is not like `JSON.stringify` (would send json format) it's different

Answer (score 0):

What the error message says is that the POST input the server received was not a valid JSON.

Probably what JQuery produces out of this input: `var people={"address": "ciao"};` isn't what you expect. You can try sniffing what was actually transmitted over the HTTP request (using Firebug, Wireshark etc.).

---

Try using:

```
var people='{"address": "ciao"}';
```

instead of

```
var people={"address": "ciao"};
```

Comment: i've tried your solution @Jiri Tousek but it doesn't work